# Jackson generic json to List<T> converter method does not work

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

```
public static <T> List<T> convertJSONStringTOListOfT(String jsonString, Class<T> t){
        if(jsonString == null){
            return null;
        }
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try
        {
            List<T> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {});
            return list;
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have the above method, when I try to invoke it using :

```
list = convertJSONStringTOListOfT(str, CustomAssessmentQuestionSetItem.class);
```

The returned list is `List<LinkedHashMap>` not `List<CustomAssessmentQuestionSetItem>`

Although if I don't use generics then the below code works fine :

```
list = mapper.readValue(str, new TypeReference<List<CustomAssessmentQuestionSetItem>>() {});
```

Both invocations appear the same to me. Unable to understand why the generic one is creating a `List<LinkedHashMap>` instead of `List<CustomAssessmentQuestionSetItem>`

FYI : I've also tried changing the method signature to

```
public static <T> List<T> convertJSONStringTOListOfT(String jsonString, T t)
```

and the corresponding invocation to

```
list = convertJSONStringTOListOfT(str,new CustomAssessmentQuestionSetItem());
```

but it didn't worked.

Comment: You're not actually using your parameter `t`.

Comment: Neither does he - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24997/566092, tried using gives compile errors.

Comment: Right, and the comments do tell him that it's wrong.

Comment: oh I see now, but there's still no link to what'll work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have the element class you probably want to use your mapper's `TypeFactory` like this:

```
final TypeFactory factory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
final JavaType listOfT = factory.constructCollectionType(List.class, t);
```

Then use `listOfT` as your second argument to `.readValue()`.